# Status of setcontext / getcontext in BSD and Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, posix, freebsd

I am using setcontext / getcontext for creating coroutines in C. The current software is implemented for ARMv7 using Linux 3.18 Kernel. Since these apis are deprecated, i couldn't find proper information regarding to their development status. I have read that they are reimplemented for ARM but deprecated on x86 oses. However, i can still find up-to-date Man pages for [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setcontext&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011-current&arch=default&format=html) and [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcontext.3.html). There aren't any warnings or notices regarding to their use.

Is it a reliable choice to continue using them ? Why do they still exists in libc ? What is the status in Linux kernel 4 ?

Thanks

Comment: Read the `Rationale` in the old POSIX, SUS v6: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/makecontext.html

Comment: The APIs aren't going to vanish any time soon, they are part of old standards and as such there is a good reason to keep them. They are also used by many programs, giving even less reason for libc maintainers to remove them.

Comment: In the FreeBSD manual pages there is no mention of these functions being deprecated.